# why dompdf inside laravel 4.2 failes to load html string?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

Inside the `laravel` controller, When I do this

```
$html = '<h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
        <h2>Basic HTML Example</h2>
        This file demonstrates most of the HTML elements.
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
        <h6>Heading 6</h6>';

$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadHTML($html);
$pdf->save('my_stored_invoice.pdf')
```

It works perfectly.

But when i do this

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadView('pdf.invoice');
$pdf->save('my_stored_invoice.pdf');
```

My browser crashes with the calling URL, Also `apache` got slowed down.

I have set `INI` limit `2048 MB`.

Please suggest me some way to get out of this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the similar prob. by someone here http://www.dashinteractive.net/dompdf/index.php?v=3198802

Comment: Try this: `$html = view('pdf.invoice')->render(); $pdf = App::make('dompdf'); $pdf->loadHTML($html); $pdf->save('my_stored_invoice.pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

Isnt really an answer but too big to fit in comments... Few things to try:

Check installed:

```
PHP version 5.3.0 or higher
DOM extension
GD extension
MBString extension
php-font-lib
php-svg-lib
```

Writeable folders - check to make sure that you are able to write any temporary files.

Check your logs to see what crashed?

Check top / htop / activity monitor etc to see if you are using all your ram

Answer (score 0):

Hello for this is fixed by changing the file permission

```
/vendor/thujohn/pdf
```

To allow domPDF to write temporally data